# Is this question better on the History SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Have countries ever forced an international flight to divert in order to arrest a wanted person, prior in to the Belarus incident?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/64176/have-countries-ever-forced-an-international-flight-to-divert-in-order-to-arrest)

Sure it's a current political event, but it's also asking for a history-based answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've liaised with moderators on the History stack, and we both feel that the question fits better on that site - the question is explicitly looking for historical examples and while the current event in Belarus is undeniably political, the question isn't really focused on the political aspects of the event. On the other hand, [History's help center](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) mentions "Factual current political history questions" in particular.

I've migrated the question.

Comment: D'accord. But a tiny procedural suggestion: H:SE aims to *require* 'documented prior research' for a Q. This one has none. As such, its quality is undeniably sub-par for what we want on that site.  Such migrations are frequent: topic fits, but style/'quality' comes about as mismatch (compare mod-comment on this one now) Is there any way you can think of to get Qs about to be migrated up to speed on this? Like, eg pinging OP to nudge OP into activity into that direction (including a short wait period?) *before* migration takes place?

Comment: @LаngLаngС I agree there's a bit of a mismatch there, however the discussion I had with the mod over on History was to the effect that their community would be best placed to knock it into shape re quality. I think that's probably right - their community has the best knowledge to fix the question to their standards.

Comment: D'accord again. Nobody did wrong, imo. I'd agree that extensive edits before migrating would be even more problematic (especially if mig rejected). AFAIK, now it is: migrations suggested (here even on meta), [mods contact each other, seems optional], migration takes place, *then* OP gets to know what happened/happens & that there might be different expectations on Qs. My suggestion aims at giving OPs some heads-up so that they can prepare better, earlier. Less 'punishment' for OPs (happens), better Qs faster (urgently needed, should they get HNQ'd).